# batch check if windows 7 is permanently activated

Tags: windows, windows-activation

I need a simple command in batch to check if windows 7 is permanently activated ( no kms activated)

for example:

```
If windows 7 is permanently activated

              echo cool

else

              echo "You have to buy a legit key"
```

Comment: slmgr.vbs /xpr should work..

Comment: no it doesn't. It just outputs a window. I need to implement it in a batch. If it does show me a code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using wscript instead of cscript. Try this:

```
@echo off
cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1
if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (echo Not permanently activated.) else (echo Permanently activated)
exit /b
```

You may have to check the output of `cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr` on the system that you're using as your test, and then modify the string to search for in the `findstr` line to show a proper message.

Hope that helps.